# Be Published From/By

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I have a question about "be published from" [here](http://online.wsj.com/articles/vote-for-scotland-independence-could-usher-in-economic-uncertainty-1410968065):

> A report ***published*** Tuesday ***from*** Angus Armstrong and Monique Ebell of the National Institute of Economic and Social Research, a private think tank, estimates Scotland would face twin deficits in its first year: a budget deficit of over 6% of gross domestic product and a current-account shortfall—the balance of trade in goods and services with net interest payments—of a similar magnitude.

Would "be published ***by***" be the same as "be published ***from***"?

Comment: Your link requires a subscription so I can't check it. But I would say "published by" refers the the publisher/publication, not the writers (Angus Armstrong and Monique Ebell).

Comment: It is not a report published *by* or *from* anybody; it is a report *from* the authors which was published on Tuesday.

Answer (score 4):

"From" is referring to the "report" (not to "published").

Here's the same text rearranged and simplfied:

> A report from Angus Armstrong and Monique Ebell of the National Institute of Economic and Social Research, a private think tank, was published Tuesday. It estimates [...]

Comment: I'd prefer *published on Tuesday* myself. I *think* that leaving out the *on* is American.

Comment: @TRiG Yeah, "published Tuesday" often confuses me too. I deliberately kept the original text's wording here though, to make it clearer what got rearranged.

Comment: @TRiG By the way, English SE has [a question about that](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111217/is-it-common-to-omit-a-preposition-in-on-of-before-the-month-year-week) and it indeed seems to be mostly an Americanism.

Answer (score 3):

I think in your example, **from** is not describing **published**.  It's not "be published from", it's "published, from".  Since (native speaker gut check here) "published" doesn't take "from", the "published Tuesday" phrase reads as a parenthetical, and that it might have been better punctuated:

> A report published Tuesday, from Angus Armstrong and Monique Ebell of the National Institute of Economic and Social Research, a private think tank, estimates...

But doing so would have betrayed just how many parentheticals were snuck in there (a stylistic problem I sympathize with, being as I am so very prone to it).